# vdoc for php in Netbeans 6.9.1 seems not working

Tags: netbeans, autocomplete, code-templates

When I insert a vdoc, like discriped [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/defining_a_variable_type_in), Netbeans not offers any suggestions:

```
/* @var $persistenceManager Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Manager */
$persistenceManager = t3lib_div::makeInstance('Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Manager');
$persistenceManager-> // no suggestions here
```

The switch of variablename and type has not changed the result. What is it, what I'm making wrong or is it just a bug?

My Netbeans Version:

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 6.9.1 (Build 201011082200)
Java: 1.6.0_23; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 19.0-b09
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on x86; Cp1252; de_DE (nb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it is not *technically* a bug, but it is just as annoying as a mosquito buzzing in your ear. :-)

The expansion of code templates from their abbreviations can be short-circuited by a few things. For example, if you start to type the abbreviation, make a mistake, backspace to erase and correct just a few characters but not the whole thing, then NetBeans won't detect that the abbreviation for the template was typed, and thus won't expand it. A little more commonly, if what you type opens up the auto-completion pop-up first, then the expansion of code templates is also stopped.

When I tried out vdoc, the auto-completion pop-up got in the way for me. Likely, it is the same for you. If you type it quickly enough with the expansion key so that the auto-completion does not pop-up, it will probably work.

Unfortunately, there is no easy switch or setting to control how quickly auto-completion shows up. Fortunately, there ***is*** a way to set it.  I am assuming from your link and interest in "vdoc" that you are working on PHP files, so we'll set the auto-completion delay for that.

- Open windows explorer and go to `%USERPROFILE%\.netbeans\config\Editors\text`. (`%USERPROFILE%` can be typed directly into the explorer path bar just like it was a path itself, or you can go to the `C:\Users\`*your-log-in-name* directory.)
- Unless you already have one (I didn't) create a directory called `x-php5`
- Inside *that* directory, create a sub-directory called `Preferences`
- Inside ***that*** directory, create a text file named:
  `org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomPreferences.xml`
- Open that file with a text editor, and put in the following:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE editor-preferences PUBLIC "-//NetBeans//DTD Editor Preferences 1.0//EN" "http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/EditorPreferences-1_0.dtd">
  <editor-preferences>
      <entry name="completion-auto-popup-delay" value="3000" />
  </editor-preferences>
  ```
- Save it.
- Stop and restart your NetBeans.
- Give code template expansion a try.

The `completion-auto-popup-delay` is set in milliseconds, so the above resets it to ***three (3) seconds***. That is *obviously* too long to be useful. Once you get the code completion expansion working properly, go back in and edit the XML configuration file, and reduce the delay in increments until you are comfortable that you have both enough time to type and expand a code template, and that your auto-completion pop-up doesn't take an inordinate amount of time to react. It will be a balancing act.

I don't know if it is strictly needed, but I made sure to stop and re-start NetBeans each time I made a change to the XML file.

***Also***:

Make sure you are typing the correct expansion key(s) after the abbreviation. I changed mine to <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> and forgot all about it.

- In NetBeans, Click on *Tools* then *Options*
- In the Options dialog, click on the *Editor* icon in the toolbar
- Click on the *Code Templates* tab
- Check (and if necessary, change) the *Expand Template on* setting

  [image]

Comment: Thanks for you detailed answer! I have disabled the **"Auto Popup Completion Window"**, find in Tools > Options > Editor > Code Completion > All Languages.

No popup has been shown, but it still does not work.

Comment: Hmmm, there might be something else getting in the way. Or maybe it is still auto-completion. Try the above just for kicks, even though you turned it off. Maybe the timer is still active even if it doesn't end up popping up? (I'm grasping at straws here.) Also when you try it, try something other than vdoc that is very easy and quick to type and type it and the expansion key (space, shift+space, tab, enter, whatever you have it set to) as fast as you can.

Comment: Awesome Robert! It works with adding the **completion-auto-popup-delay** to preferences manually. But I'm a little bit confused, cause adding phpDoc for methods doesn't make trouble here. However, thanks a lot!

Comment: Wow! OK. Didn't really expect that to work to be honest. :-) I would consider this definitely a bug that you should file with NetBeans: Disabling Auto Popup Completion Window should have solved the problem because the completion-auto-popup-delay should the not have mattered. Obviously, though, the delay is still active, and it must be that the disabled setting is only checked _after_ the popup delay expires. _Definitely_ **not** how I would have written it. What must be happening is that as you type v-d-o-... the popup tries to happen, but is disabled and so does not, but still kills the exp.

Comment: By "adding phpDoc..." I assume you mean typing `/**[Enter]` to get the doc block. I don't think that triggers an auto-completion pop-up, so it is not killed before it expands. Something like v-d-o... has a very good chance of triggering auto-completion though.

Comment: Added to the NetBeans bug database as [issue 194091](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=194091).

Comment: This issue [(194019)](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=194091) and [another](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=194091) auto-completion / code template bug have been marked as fixed for NetBeans 7.0. The fixed will probably show up in the nightly builds soon, and will probably also be in the next beta (or RC if that's their next release).